# Custom markerInfoWindow disabling touch after it appears on Google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers

I am using GoogleMaps 2.0.1 i have to show custom pop up or custom marker window on its tap.It should be look like below:

[image]

**This is how my custom marker class is look like:**

```
import UIKit

class MapPopUp: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblName : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDesc : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnClose : UIButton!
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        var nibContents = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("MapPopUp", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(nibContents[0] as! UIView)

    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        guard superview != nil else {
            return
        }
        self.superview!.autoresizesSubviews = false
    }
}
```

**These are my google map delegate**

```
 func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker) -> UIView? {

        let vc =  MapPopUp(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 310, 70))
        vc.lblName.text = "N/A"
        vc.lblDesc.text = "N/A"

        vc.btnClose.addTarget(self,action:#selector(MapVC.closeAction(_:)),
                         forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)


        if let dict = marker.userData as? NSDictionary
        {
            if let strName = dict.objectForKey("name") as? String
            {
               vc.lblName.text = strName
            }
            if let strDesc = dict.objectForKey("description") as? String
            {
               vc.lblDesc.text = strDesc
            }
        }
        vc.layoutIfNeeded()
        vc.layoutSubviews()
        return vc
   }


    func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

     var point = mapView.projection.pointForCoordinate(marker.position)
     point.x = point.x + 100



     let vancouverCam = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(marker.position)
        mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(vancouverCam)
    self.mapView.selectedMarker = marker
        return true
    }

func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOfMarker marker:    GMSMarker)
     {
        self.mapView.selectedMarker = nil

     }
```

Isuue is after tapping to marker, it is showing me correct marker info window but after it google map get stuck and it is not hiding the marker info window again.

Thanks in Advance!!